# Move controls in the designer with keyboard

Tags: microsoft-dynamics

how to move controls in the designer with the keyboard?

Normal you can do that with ctrl+ arrows.

But that doesnt work.

This is what I mean. How to move controls with keyboard
[image]

Thank you

Comment: Are you designing what? And what is the NAV version?

Comment: Microsoft dynamics navision

Comment: Hi, OK, but designing what? I think it's Ctrl+Shift+Arrow is that what you want...

Answer (score 0):

(thanks for the comments)
sorry, but you can't move the Controls using the Keyboard in the Form Designer. You have to use the mouse for that.

Cheers!